# How to take ints from Action Event into an array to create a circle in Java?

Tags: java, paintcomponent

I am having a huge problem in Java creating a GUI that takes input from a user and creates a circle based on that input.  I am taking input from the user and holding the values within the getUserX, getUserY, getRadius and circleColor, however I have no idea how to pass these variables into an array that's used by the paint component to make a circle.

How do I properly take the value of the getUserX, getUserY and getRadius variables and put them into the circleValues array?  How do I take the circleColor taken from the user's input and put it as the page.setColor value for the created circle?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class CircleMaker 
{

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    BuildsFrame();
}

public static void BuildsFrame()
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Circle Drawer");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JTabbedPane tp = new JTabbedPane();
    tp.addTab ("Intro", new IntroPanel());
    tp.addTab("Your Circle!", new CirclePanel());

    frame.getContentPane().add(tp);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

}

class IntroPanel extends JPanel
{
public IntroPanel()
{
    final JTextField xCoorTF, yCoorTF, radiusTF;
    int userXcoor, userYcoor, userRadius;

    JButton makeButton = new JButton("Create!");
    final JColorChooser colorChooser;


    setLayout (new FlowLayout());
    setBackground (Color.gray);
    setPreferredSize (new Dimension(700, 500));

    JLabel l1 = new JLabel ("Enter your desired coordinates and radius for your circle.");
    JLabel l2 = new JLabel ("Please type the X coordinate in the first box, the");
    JLabel l3 = new JLabel ("Y coordinates in the second box,");
    JLabel l4 = new JLabel ("and the radius of your circle");
    JLabel l5 = new JLabel ("in the final box.");

    xCoorTF = new JTextField(5);
    yCoorTF = new JTextField(5);
    radiusTF = new JTextField(5);



    colorChooser = new JColorChooser();
    colorChooser.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Choose Circle Color:"));



    makeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            int getUserX = Integer.parseInt(xCoorTF.getText());
            int getUserY = Integer.parseInt(yCoorTF.getText());
            int getRadius = Integer.parseInt(radiusTF.getText());
            Color circleColor = colorChooser.getColor();
            System.out.println(getUserX);
            System.out.println(getUserY);
            System.out.println(getRadius);

        }   
    });



    add (l1);
    add (l2);
    add (l3);
    add (l4);
    add (l5);
    add (xCoorTF);
    add (yCoorTF);
    add (radiusTF);
    add (colorChooser);
    add (makeButton);

}
}

class CirclePanel extends JPanel
{
int[] circleValues = {50, 50, 100}; 

circleValues[0] = getUserX;
circleValues[1] = getUserY;
circleValues[2] = getRadius;

public CirclePanel()
{
    setBackground (Color.WHITE);

}

public void paintComponent (Graphics page)
{
    super.paintComponent (page);
    page.setColor (Color.BLACK);
    page.fillOval((circleValues[0] - 2), (circleValues[1] - 2), (circleValues[2] + 4), (circleValues[2] + 4));
    page.setColor (Color.GRAY);
    page.fillOval (circleValues[0], circleValues[1], (circleValues[2]), (circleValues[2]));
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike many other languages, commands cannot be "floating in space" in Java.

You will need to raise the scope of that data as well as move your *circleValues* array fill to a segment of code that will be executed.

Comment: My knowledge of coding is very limited.  I do not know how to ensure that these lines of code are executed; I assumed they were being executed, but I'm still learning to code so I'm just kinda winging it.